# Class methods not working

Tags: java

For some reason, my Move() function in the class TicTacToeBoard is not working.

Here is the main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TicTakToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What player are you(X or O)?");
        String player = in.next();
        System.out.println("What row do you want to play in(top, middle, bottom)?");
        String row = in.next();
        System.out.println("What column do you want to play in(left, center, right)?");
        String column = in.next();

        System.out.println(player + ", " + row + ", " + column);
        TicTacToeBoard one = new TicTacToeBoard(player, row, column);
        one.Move();
        one.printBoard();
        int counter = 1;

        while(counter <= 9){

            System.out.println("What player are you(X or O)?");
            player = in.next();
            System.out.println("What row do you want to play in(top, middle, bottom)?");
            row = in.next();
            System.out.println("What column do you want to play in(left, center, right)?");
            column = in.next();

            System.out.println(player + ", " + row + ", " + column);

            one.Move();
            counter ++;
            one.printBoard();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class TicTacToeBoard {

    private int[][]board = {
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,0},
        {0,0,0} };

    String row, column, player;

    //Constructor
    public TicTacToeBoard(String r, String c, String p){
        row = r;
        column = c;
        player = p;
        }


    public void Move(){
        if (row == "top" && column == "left" && player == "X"){
            board[0][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "top" && column == "center" && player == "X"){
            board[0][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "top" && column == "right" && player == "X"){
            board[0][2] = 1;
        } 


        if (row == "middle" && column == "left" && player == "X"){
            board[1][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "middle" && column == "center" && player == "X"){
            board[1][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "middle" && column == "right" && player == "X"){
            board[1][2] = 1;
        } 


        if (row == "bottom" && column == "left" && player == "X"){
            board[2][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "bottom" && column == "center" && player == "X"){
            board[2][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "bottom" && column == "right" && player == "X"){
            board[2][2] = 1;
        } 





        if (row == "top" && column == "left" && player == "Y"){
            board[0][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "top" && column == "center" && player == "Y"){
            board[0][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "top" && column == "right" && player == "Y"){
            board[0][2] = 1;
        } 


        if (row == "middle" && column == "left" && player == "Y"){
            board[1][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "middle" && column == "center" && player == "Y"){
            board[1][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "middle" && column == "right" && player == "Y"){
            board[1][2] = 1;
        } 


        if (row == "bottom" && column == "left" && player == "Y"){
            board[2][0] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "bottom" && column == "center" && player == "Y"){
            board[2][1] = 1;
        }
        if (row == "bottom" && column == "right" && player == "Y"){
            board[2][2] = 1;
        }
    }

    public void printBoard(){
        for(int i = 0;i <= 2;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= 2;j++){
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is:

What player are you(X or O)?

X

What row do you want to play in(top, middle, bottom)?

top

What column do you want to play in(left, center, right)?

left

X, top, left

000
000
000

What player are you(X or O)?

For some reason, the board ends up ass all zeros no matter what I input. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the javascript here ?

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1393766).

Answer (score 2):

I think first you need to replace  `row == "top"` and other string comparision using `String.equals(String)` methods

Answer (score 2):

The first problem in your code is in constructor of TicTacToeBoard

TicTacToeBoard(String r, String c, String p) the contstructor parameter expecting row,column and player but you are passing

```
TicTacToeBoard one = new TicTacToeBoard(player, row, column);
```

player, row and column Which is wrong.

Second thing is that you are not updating player,row,column value of TicTacToeBoard class in your while loop.Every time when you are taking input from user in while loop after that you have to set those values in TicTacToeBoard class also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, they are called methods in Java and not functions.

And change `row == "...."` to `row.equals(...)`because that's how we compare strings in java.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your lines like

```
 if (row == "top" && column == "left" && player == "X"){
            board[0][0] = 1;
        }
```

with

```
if ("top".equalsIgnoreCase(row) && "left".equalsIgnoreCase(column) && "X".equalsIgnoreCase(player)){
            board[0][0] = 1;
        }
```

The == operator asks if the two items are the same object ..not whether they have the same value.